# Windows installer does not clean up *.pyc and *.pyo files on uninstall

Tags: python, setuptools, windows-installer

I have a python app (PyQt4 app) for which I create a windows MSI installer using setuptools.

```
python setup.py bdist_msi
```

The MSI installs the application correctly (under site-packages).  On uninstalling (msiexec /x) it also removes all the associated *.py files.  However, the compiled files still persist on disk.  Subsequently when I run the new version of the app, it still picks up stale *.pyc files.

Is there an option to somehow tell the MSI to clean up *.pyc and *.pyo files?

(I suspect this is because *.pyc and *.pyo files were not installed by the MSI in the first place, but rather created upon running python.exe.  But would appreciate some guidance).

Thanks

Comment: See https://bugs.python.org/issue20748 "The simplest work-around could be to run pip uninstallation with -B. I just edited the MSI with orca, and that seems to work fine."

Answer (score 0):

You are absolutely correct. Msi do not remove those file because they were not deployed by installer. In order to clean them up you have to create custom-action which will delete all *.pyc and *.pyo files.

Just in case you know exact filenames you could add dummy (empty) files so that installer would consider them it's "property" and delete them on uninstall.